# getting tweets by user_mention (@user) from twitter in Android

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter4j, twitter-fabric

I am developing an Android app with twitter integration. I want to fetch tweets by `user_mention` from twitter . I saw this documentation on twitter dev http://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/show-timelines.html .

Here is the part of code:-

```
 public class TimelineActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.timeline);

        TwitterAuthConfig authConfig =  new TwitterAuthConfig("xxxxxxbbbbwdqddq", "eieuhquifhioqhfiohqoifhoi");
        Fabric.with((this), new TwitterCore(authConfig), new TweetUi());

        UserTimeline userTimeline = new UserTimeline.Builder().screenName("fabric").build();
```

Using this approach i am getting the timeline according by `screen name`. But i want all the tweets that has mentioned a particular user ( ex-`@user` )  **not the timeline**. I have tried it with `fabric` but i can try `twitter4j` also . so if you have any idea how to do this (either with `fabric` or `twitter 4j`) , it will be helpful . thanks in advance.

Comment: don't downvote without giving reasons

Answer (score 1):

For your requirement Twitter search API is the best solution. In case of Twitter Fabric you can use SearchService. You can get SearchService from Fabric's twitter client. as follows:

```
    Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));
   TwitterSession currentSession = Twitter.getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
   TwitterApiClient twitterApiClient = new TwitterApiClient(currentSession); 
   SearchService searchService       = twitterApiClient.getSearchService();
//Other services in Fabric Twitter
   AccountService accountService     =twitterApiClient.getAccountService();
   StatusesService statusesService   = twitterApiClient.getStatusesService();
   FavoriteService favoriteService   = twitterApiClient.getFavoriteService();
```

Following is the request template for Search Service:

```
public interface SearchService {
@GET("/1.1/search/tweets.json")
void tweets(@Query("q") String var1, @EncodedQuery("geocode") Geocode var2, @Query("lang") String var3, @Query("locale") String var4, @Query("result_type") String var5, @Query("count") Integer var6, @Query("until") String var7, @Query("since_id") Long var8, @Query("max_id") Long var9, @Query("include_entities") Boolean var10, Callback<Search> var11);
}
```

Here you will have to enter your query in place of **"q"**. Enter the required query and you will get your result. You can try out queries in Twitter's Developer console here [Twitter Developer Console](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/tools/console).

Sample code using it:

```
searchService.tweets("@ladygaga", null, null, null, SEARCH_RESULT_TYPE, SEARCH_COUNT, null, null,
        maxId, true, new Callback<Search>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<Search> searchResult) {
                final List<Tweet> tweets = searchResult.data.tweets;
                // Use tweets as you like
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException error) {

            }
        }
```

);

For example for searching all tweets mentioning **ladygaga** you will have your query as **https://twitter.com/search?q=%40ladygaga&src=typd**. Here q is **"%40ladygaga"**. You can try it out using your twitter account also. Check for the url in the address bar. It gives hints as to what should be query.

For more information regarding how to build queries you can have a look at 
[How to Build Twitter Search Queries](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search)
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it!. My application use very good!

```
public class...
UserTimeline userTimeline;
String username;
TwitterSession session;
TweetTimelineListAdapter adapter;
..... oncreate()....
TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig("Xcp2iipj28BMVda6OSxVAwwLz", "grZ1IJYIHUPQsrf8F8fsbA06O55bfRGENW8mPbDTspoVKcV1xS");
            Fabric.with(getActivity(), new TwitterCore(authConfig), new TweetUi());
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            }
            session = Twitter.getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
            username = session.getUserName();
            userTimeline = new UserTimeline.Builder()
                    .screenName(username)
                    .build();
            adapter = new TweetTimelineListAdapter.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setTimeline(userTimeline)
                    .build();
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: could you give some explanation to go with your answer

Comment: where do you understand?